# Tile mapping to share a map online - how do I do it?

Tags: map-making, maps

I'd like to share this very complex continent/dungeon map I've created online, and the way I'd ideally like to do it is through tiling and [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com). I love the "see only broad details, then see greater detail, then greater detail still" effect you get when you zoom into the map.

I've never tried to tile anything before. I have created the map in Inkscape, so I can go as far as creating different layers to represent the different zoom levels I'd like to create, but I really have no clue as how to go about creating these tiles.

Is there some good, free (or inexpensive) software that can walk me through this, preferably with a GUI?

Comment: In order to use something like Leaflet, you're going to have to have a map server of some kind to point it at. They link to [Cloudmade](http://cloudmade.com/) to actually create the maps, which is what you'd have to do. Serving it like this is more [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) than RPG, so you probably won't find a lot of help for the technical aspects here.

Comment: I would suggest a different Stack Exchange website for this question - perhaps [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions)? Quite honestly, this question is about tiling images, not roleplaying games. It does fit into the [on-topic criteria](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) ("Tools and equipment used when playing RPGs"), but you may not get a good answer here.

Comment: This question on GIS stackexchange might help (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5101/how-to-cut-a-tiled-image-from-a-raster-dataset-using-gdal)